# GROUP BY WEEK with SQL

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/226ae/1

I'm trying to now add one row for each week of the year, and filter the contacts accordingly.  CONTACTS has a datetime column.  The new table will look like:

```
        Status 1    Status 2    Status 3
Week 1      3          4           2
Week 2      1          5           3
Week 3      2          2           4
```

I think that DATEADD needs to be used, however I'm at a loss in terms of how to begin changing my query.

I do know that MySQL has a GROUP BY WEEK command, but I don't think that SQL has an equivalent.  What's the best way to accomplish this?

Comment: I think that your question is not clear enough

Comment: Just added more details - does this help?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You can use [`DATEPART()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx), this groups by both the week and the year in the event you have data spanning multiple years:

```
SELECT 
    'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, created) as varchar(2)) Week,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Status1,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Status2,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Status3,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Status4,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Status5
FROM contacts
group by datepart(wk, created), year(created)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/226ae/11)

Adding the year to the final result:

```
SELECT 
    'Week ' + cast(datepart(wk, created) as varchar(2)) Week,
    year(created) year,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Status1,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Status2,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Status3,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Status4,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Status5
FROM contacts
group by  datepart(wk, created), year(created)
```

See [SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/8fe9c/1)

Comment: From MSDN I was using the DATEDIFF method which does not support SET DATEFIRST 1; This answer supports first day of weeks corrrectly.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [the `datepart` function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) to extract the week from a date.

The query becomes:

```
SELECT datepart(week, created) as week,
  SUM(case WHEN status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Status1,
  SUM(case WHEN status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Status2,
  SUM(case WHEN status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Status3,
  SUM(case WHEN status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Status4,
  SUM(case WHEN status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Status5
FROM contacts
group by datepart(week, created)
```

SqlFiddle: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/226ae/6tsq

Answer (score 0):

You might try using the group by clause in your query:

```
SELECT
    DATE_FORMAT( created, '%u' ) week_number,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 1 then 1 else 0 end) Status1,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 2 then 1 else 0 end) Status2,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 3 then 1 else 0 end) Status3,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 4 then 1 else 0 end) Status4,
    SUM(case WHEN status = 5 then 1 else 0 end) Status5
FROM contacts
GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT( created, '%u' )
```

I'm assuming you are talking about mysql.

The DATE_FORMAT function is documented here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Comment: the question is about TSQL (SQL Server), not MySQL.