# How to get sum of total counts with most recent hourly / daily / weekly / yearly interval in cakephp 3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.x

I've a table as following-

[image]

Now I need to make report of total number of counts in every hour, week, month and year. It may have sum 0 but should be include on the result. For example I need the result as follows-

```
$hourlyResult = array(
'00:01' => '5',
'00:02' => '9',
'00:03' => '50',
'00:04' => '5',
..............
..............
'00:55' => '95',
'00:56' => '0',
'00:57' => '20',
'00:58' => '33',
'00:59' => '5',
);

$weeklyResult = array(
'SAT' => '500',
'SUN' => '300'
.............
.............
'FRI' => '700'
);
```

How can I build the query in cakephp 3? I got the following link but can't go so far.

[GROUP BY WEEK with SQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13278552/group-by-week-with-sql)

What I've done-

```
    $this->loadModel('Searches');   
    $searches = $this->Searches
        ->find('all')
        ->select(['created', 'count'])
        ->where('DATE(Searches.created) = DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY)')
        ->group(WEEK(date))
        ->hydrate(false)
        ->toArray();
    pr($searches);
```

Comment: `Raw` query would do?

Comment: I want to know the cakephp way. Though, I don't know the raw query also.

Comment: Okay. Then you have to wait until a `cake php` guy drops by.

Comment: If you don't mind can you please tell me the raw query way as cakephp supports raw query also. If I not found any cakephp guy then I'll implement on raw way.

Comment: Then I need more info: what does your expected output look like? By `weekly` did you mean week/ last 7 days? In fact your expected output will answer so many questions.

Comment: Got answer of one of the questions. Now, it's turn for **expected output**

Comment: Did you get anything? @1000111

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how you can do it.

**Sum By Year**

```
    $query = $this->Searches->find();
    $query = $this->Searches
        ->find()
        ->select([
            'total_count' => $query->func()->sum('count'),
            'year' => $query->func()->year(['created' => 'literal'])
        ])
        ->group(['year'])
        ->hydrate(false);
```

**Or**

```
    $query = $this->Searches
        ->find()
        ->select(['total_count' => 'SUM(count)', 'year' => 'YEAR(created)'])
        ->group(['year'])
        ->hydrate(false);
```

**Sum By Day Of Week**

```
    $query = $this->Searches->find();
    $query = $this->Searches
        ->find()
        ->select([
            'total_count' => $query->func()->sum('count'),
            'day_of_week' => $query->func()->dayOfWeek('created')
        ])
        ->group(['day_of_week'])
        ->hydrate(false);
```

**Or**

```
    $query = $this->Searches
        ->find()
        ->select(['total_count' => 'SUM(count)', 'day_of_week' => 'DAYOFWEEK(created)'])
        ->group(['day_of_week'])
        ->hydrate(false);
```

The same way you can get total sum by hour or month.
Here you can read about [CakePHP > Using SQL Functions](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/query-builder.html#using-sql-functions) and [date and time functions in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_month).